# SendGrid Event Webhook ASP.NET MVC Post is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

I hope someone can help. I have an ASP.NET MVC website running via Azure. Ultimate goal here is to log SendGrid events to a database.  First I need to get the JSON sent by SendGrid.  I have turned on Event Notification under `Settings--> Mail Settings--> Event Notification`.  Using Postman and Streaming Logs in Azure and Azure remote debugging, I have determined that my controller is indeed receiving the POST request from SendGrid, however I am not getting any JSON.

I've tried the following:

In the example below, json is null:

```
public ActionResult SendGridOne(string json)
```

In the example below, eventList is null (note this is using the Sendgrid.Webhooks nuget package):

```
public ActionResult SendGridOne([FromBody]SendGridEvents[] eventList)
```

Also have tried the following, but rawSendGridJSON is always null:

```
public ActionResult SendGridOne()
        {

            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream);
            string rawSendGridJSON = reader.ReadToEnd();
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(rawSendGridJSON);
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at the `Request`. Is the `Content-Type` set to `application/json`, etc?

Comment: I'm not sure as SendGrid sends the request not me

Comment: There's a `Request` property on your controller. Use the debugger to inspect it inside of `SendGridOne`.

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize that was there.  The Content-Type is indeed application/json. The only thing that stands out is HttpChannelBinding threw an exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'. The Microsoft docs have not been helpful about this and some SO posts have said it can just happen in debug mode...

Comment: Try sending some data to your endpoint yourself, using something like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: Actually I did try that and I'm having the same issue.  So maybe this is really a separate question about ASP.NET MVC receiving json post data...

Comment: It would appear so. If you can't figure it out, update your question and include your `SendGridEvents` class and sample JSON you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The Sendgrid.Webhooks nuget package is correct. I test with this form, its works correctly:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Sendgrid.Webhooks.Service;

namespace WebHookSendgrid.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class WebHookController : ControllerBase
    {

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost("Sendgridwh")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Sendgridwh([FromBody] object[] eventList)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventList);

            var parser = new WebhookParser();
            var events = parser.ParseEvents(json);
       
            // this is custom method, you can make yours for your needs  
            await sendGridService.EmailActivity(events);
            
            return new OkResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Visit [Sendgrid Webhooks](https://github.com/mirajavora/sendgrid-webhooks) on Github